# Apple Terminal script to copy files based on a .csv list of filenames?

Tags: macos, terminal

Been trying for hours to get this to work - but I'm a complete novice (e.g. started using terminal today) and struggling to get this working.

I have a csv file that lists filenames row by row. I want to find them and copy them to a new directory. The files are listed in one directory, but each file is in its own subdirectory.

This is what I have tried, but it is not copying anything. But I can see it cycling through the searches:

```
    cat /Users/Will/Downloads/three-new.csv | while IFS=, read col1
do
    find /Volumes/LaCie\ 8tb/BPOTY/2021\ Photos -path $col1 -exec cp {} /Volumes/LaCie\ 8tb/BPOTY/2021\ book \;
done
```

I have also tried this, but it just copies all files from the directory (stripping the subdirectories) and doesn't find the actual filenames.

```
cat /Users/Will/Downloads/three-new.csv | while IFS=, read col1
do
    find /Volumes/LaCie\ 8tb/BPOTY/2021\ Photos $col1 -exec cp {} /Volumes/LaCie\ 8tb/BPOTY/2021\ book \;
done
```

The file can be seen here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6uqwzky43r25ors/three.csv?dl=0

Have run a command as requested and the CSV outputs:

```
00000000: 636f 6c31 0d0a 494d 475f 3437 3538 2d64  col1..IMG_4758-d
00000010: 6e2e 6a70 670d 0a43 4f45 5f32 3330 352d  n.jpg..COE_2305-
00000020: 4564 6974 2e74 6966 2e7a 6970 0d0a 5f44  Edit.tif.zip.._D
00000030: 5343 3435 3933 2d68 6972 6573 2d72 6573  SC4593-hires-res
00000040: 6f6c 7574 696f 6e2d 5065 7465 722d 6365  olution-Peter-ce
00000050: 6368 2d54 6865 2d6c 6f6f 6b2e 6a70 67    ch-The-look.jpg
```

Comment: You need to include a representative sample of the **CSV** _file_.

Comment: I see at least two problems, though there isn't enough information here to tell if they're what's making it fail. First, `read col1` will put entire lines (not just values from the first column) into `col1` (because `read` puts any extra fields in the last variable), so use `read col1 ignored` (and then don't use the `ignored` variable). Second, you need to double-quote variable references, i.e. `"$col1"` instead of just `$col1`. [Shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at pointing out common mistakes like this, and I strongly recommend it.

Comment: @user3439894 https://www.dropbox.com/s/6uqwzky43r25ors/three.csv?dl=0

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks. I have tried this but the command running in the terminal top bar then shows -name ?? instead of the actual filename.

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script, so it'll print a trace of what it's doing. Oh, and while you're debugging it'd be safer to make it just `echo` the `cp` commands instead of (trying to) run them -- that is, replace `... -exec cp ...` with `... -exec echo cp ...`

Comment: @GordonDavisson it comes back with`+ IFS=,
+ read col1 ignored
+ set -x find '/Volumes/LaCie 8tb/BPOTY/2021 Photos' -path $'?\200\234\200\235' -exec echo cp '{}' '/Volumes/LaCie 8tb/BPOTY/2021 book' ';'
+ IFS=,
+ read col1 ignored
+ set -x find '/Volumes/LaCie 8tb/BPOTY/2021 Photos' -path $'?\200\234\200\235' -exec echo cp '{}' '/Volumes/LaCie 8tb/BPOTY/2021 book' ';'
+ IFS=,
+ read col1 ignored
`

Comment: There's something really weird with that csv file. The one you put on Dropbox is in DOS/Windows format, which is a problem (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)), but that trace indicates completely different. Try viewing the file's contents with `xxd /Users/Will/Downloads/three-new.csv` and edit the results into your question.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Looks like you're right. Added that into the question.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I put the values into a google sheet and exported as .csv -- same result.

Comment: In **Terminal**: `tr -d '\r' < three.csv > new.csv` to create a new _file_ without the _carriage returns_.

Comment: @user3439894 have run that (with the paths) and then tried running the script on the new file: `+ IFS=,
+ read col1
+ set -x find '/Volumes/LaCie 8tb/BPOTY/2021 Photos' -path $'?\200\234\200\235' -exec echo cp '{}' '/Volumes/LaCie 8tb/BPOTY/2021 book' ';'
+ IFS=,
+ read col1`

Comment: So to be clear, there is only one _column_ in the **CSV** _file_ and there are actually no _commas_ and the entries are not quoted, correct?

Comment: @user3439894 correct

Comment: @user3439894 It runs but says "-bash: cd: /Volumes/LaCie\ 8tb/BPOTY/2021\ Photos: No such file or directory". I wonder if this is because the files are each within their own subdirectory one level deeper?

Comment: Do not escape the _spaces_ with a `\\`, just _quote_ the _paths_.

Comment: @user3439894 Tried that after and it says: `find: -f: unknown primary or operator
find: -f: unknown primary or operator`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo:  `find . -type f -iname "$line" -exec cp -av {} "/path/to/destnation_dir" \;`

Comment: @user3439894 it copied the first two, but not the third. progress! weirdly, I tried it again (after removing the copied files) and it didn't repeat. For the life of me can't get it to happen again successfully.

Comment: It didn't copy the third line because there is no _linefeed_ at the end of it.

Comment: @user3439894 What do you mean by line feed please? I can't get it to repeat for some reason.

Comment: Whenever I rerun the script you gave me, nothing happens and then command just hangs.

Comment: The third line of the **CSV** _file_ does not have a _line feed_ after it. Open the file, place the cursor at the end of the third line and press _enter_ and save the file.

Comment: BTW I just tested the _code_ I posted after correcting it as shown in the previous comment and it works.

Comment: @user3439894 Ok - that's fine. However the problem now is the script just won't run anymore. I'm putting exactly the same thing in. I've tried exiting, reopening terminal and running it again but it just gives me two audible "ding" noises and nothing happens. Just stays with > on the command line.

Comment: @user3439894 This is what I'm running - which initially did work. But it's now just hanging: `#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
 cd "/Volumes/LaCie 8tb/BPOTY/2021 Photos" || exit
 find . -type f -iname "$line" -exec cp -av {} "/Volumes/LaCie 8tb/BPOTY/2021 book" \;
done < "/Users/Will/Downloads/new.csv”`

Comment: The closing _double-quote_ is bad.

Comment: @user3439894 AMAZING! That was it. My friend, I can't thank you enough for helping me. This has been such a stressful evening as this task is necessary for something I have a deadline for tomorrow. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your are doing this under **macOS** and the *file* has **CRLF** endings, first lets remove the *carriage  returns* from the **three.csv** *file*, in **Terminal**:

```
tr -d '\r' < three.csv > new.csv
```

As the **three.csv** *file* only has one column and there are actually no commas, nor are the entries quoted, this is really not a **CSV** *file* and can be treated in a more straight forward manner. To that end, use the following *shell script syntax* to accomplish your goal.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
    cd '/path/to/parent_dir' || exit
    find . -type f -iname "$line" -exec cp -av {} '/path/to/destnation_dir' \;
done < '/path/to/new.csv'
```

---

**Notes**:

- The `cd '/path/to/parent_dir' || exit` isn't absolutely necessary, it's just my preferred method in many use cases. The `.` after `find` can be replaced with `'/path/to/parent_directory'`.
- *Pathnames* with *spaces* need to either be escaped with a *backslash character* or the *pathname* be quoted, single, or double if containing *variables*, however, **not** both. As a general rule I almost alway quote *non-variable strings* with *single-quotes*. (I did use *double-quotes* last night on *non-variable strings* but that was a typo.)
- If executing directly in **Terminal** then the `#!/bin/bash` *shebang* isn't necessary and was included if using it as a standalone *shell script*.
- The last line of the **three.csv** *file*, and thus the **new.csv** *file* does not have a *line feed character*. Edit the *file* by placing the *cursor* at the end of line three and press *enter*, then save the *file*. Otherwise the last line is not processed.
- As mentioned in the *comments* of the OP by Gordon Davisson, quote your *variables* and use [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to check your `bash` *shell script code*.